# Excel VBA store countifs output for further operation

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an application in VBA for excel. Using some conditions and counting the number of records by the following functions which is working fine.

```
   cnt = appExcel.Application.CountIfs(R1, AuditType, R2, "Fail", UserRange1, UserName & "*")
```

Here R1,R2 and UserRange1 are Range types which is describing individual cells.
If we print

```
R1.Address  '$E:$E
R2.Address ' $M:$M so on.
```

I am getting the number of rows present with those criteria in "cnt" variable.

I need further manipulation like searching some custom cells from the above range of cells. To do that I need to store those addresses in a "Range" object. 
  Please guide me how can I store those filtered records in a range. I don't want to copy to another area also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a new range to a worksheet by declaring a Name object in VBA and then setting it's RefersTo value to the address.  This example adds the needed declarations and code to do this.  It assumes that you are interested in the cells in your R1 range which contain constants:

```
Dim rngFiltered As Excel.Range
Dim nmNew As Excel.Name

'...

Set rngFiltered = R1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set nmNew = ws.Names.Add(Name:="NewRange", RefersTo:="=" & rngFiltered.Address)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think named ranges can not be created only for filtered contents. They take all the rows from beginning to ending.

Comment: If you've applied an autofilter, you can specify xlCellTypeVisible.  I changed the code above to do that.  Is that what you want?  I'm not sure how your "custom cells" are filtered.

Comment: Thank you, I got some example code for auto filter, your solution can be added on that to get my result.  

            .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter

            .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=35

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you mean, insert a named range which defines the range referenced.

Excel 2003 Insert>Name>Define

Excel 2010 Formulas>Define Name